# Error with phpmyadmin importing into my localhost database

Tags: wordpress, import, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

When I impost database in my localhost xampp server database it's saying:

```
    Error
SQL offer:


INSERT INTO `wp_fv_DigiWidgetsTemplates` (`templateID`, `templateTitle`, `canvasWidth`, `canvasHeight`) VALUES
(1, 'Small Horizontal', 300, 200),
(2, 'Small Vertical', 200, 300),
(3, 'Large Horizontal', 600, 400),
(4, 'Large Vertical', 400, 600)
MySQL answer: "Документация" (that is my bulgarian localhost)`

 #1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'id'
```

Any help will be much appricated!

Comment: Check your DB is there any default entry is there, if enter is there then you have to remove it then import

Comment: There is no database - no tables!

Comment: Please watch the [video](https://youtu.be/6dhjHCuzQDk)!

Answer (score 0):

first browse your databse table ensure thatthere exists, already, id in 1 as:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_fv_DigiWidgetsTemplates`;
```

To remove this conflict either you edit your preexisting data or importing package one.
Furthermore, you can set `templateID` as auto-increasing and insert it as NULL as:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_fv_DigiWidgetsTemplates` (`templateID`, `templateTitle`, `canvasWidth`, `canvasHeight`) VALUES
(NULL, 'Small Horizontal', 300, 200),
(NULL, 'Small Vertical', 200, 300),
(NULL, 'Large Horizontal', 600, 400),
(NULL, 'Large Vertical', 400, 600);
```

Comment: There are no tables and I enter my sql into the Import menu and there is the error!

Comment: wait,what. if there is no database and table then how can you insert. There's already a record in the table having ID=1. Since ID is the PRIMARY KEY, there cannot be multiple records with the same value.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QHBj4brHNMThis may help you. watch carefully. 2:23 A_I and primary key.

Comment: ,but how it can help me

Answer (score 0):

your table have already value 1 in 'templateID', Here 'templateID' is primary key and auto-increment so no need to declare here.

you can use this code -

> INSERT INTO `wp_fv_DigiWidgetsTemplates` (`templateTitle`,
>   `canvasWidth`, `canvasHeight`) VALUES ('Small Horizontal', 300, 200),
>   ('Small Vertical', 200, 300), ('Large Horizontal', 600, 400), ('Large
>   Vertical', 400, 600);